# Error when trying to upload apk to Firebase App Distribution

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-app-distribution

I want to try the new Firebase App Distribution feature, but the moment I drag my apk to upload it and create a new distribution, I get this error: "Something went wrong. 'app-release.apk' failed to upload."

As the documentation says (https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution/android/distribute-console), I'm following my normal build process and signing the apk. I've tried signin it with my app signin key, with the debug key, with V1 signature, V2 signature, and with both V1 and V2.

Comment: Please contact Firebase support directly if you're having problems with the Firebase console.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm facing the exact same problem with my app.

Comment: @JuanCarlosDurini Yes, in my case, the problem was related with Firefox. Using Chrome to access the firebase console I was able to upload the apk.

Comment: @JuanCarlosDurini don't tell anyone, but I actually used Chromium

Comment: For me too, same error in Firefox. But worked in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem and finally figure out the reason behind it. The problem is **very low or unstable uploading speed** of my ISP. Then I have tried to upload my APK with a **high and stable uploading speed** internet and it works fine.

Comment: I have good internet reception still, I face this issue

Answer (score -1):

Same problem, but I'm using Chrome.
When apk was uploaded, firebase have requested for checking that uploading item for existing, but response was error "ENTITY_NOT_FOUND" with 404 code.

Comment: In my case problem was with application icon. You should set icon in Manifest even for test app distribution.

Comment: This is not a solution (what answer should be). It should have beena a comment.